# Unable to claim USB interface with C + libusb on Mac OS X

Tags: c, usb, libusb, cdc, libusb-1.0

I've got a compound USB + CDC device I built using a PIC32 microcontroller, and I'm trying to connect to the device and send some data to the CDC data interface endpoint from my Mac.

I know the circuit works 100%, as the device registers as both a HID joystick, and I'm able to connect to the device using Zoc terminal, on /dev/tty.usbmodemfa132. I can send commands with [Zoc](http://www.emtec.com/zoc/), and see my MCU responding to these commands by blinking some LEDs on the circuit.

I'm running this on Mac OS X Mavericks, but had the same problem with a similar example I gave up on, a few weeks ago on Mountain Lion.

My code looks like follows:

```
// Includes -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libusb-1.0/libusb.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// Defines ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#define VID 0x04d8
#define PID 0x005e
#define CDC_DATA_INTERFACE_ID 2

// Function Declarations ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void print_device(libusb_device *device);
void send(libusb_context *usb_context, uint16_t vid, uint16_t pid);

// Function Definitions -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * main
 */
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    libusb_device **usb_devices = NULL;
    libusb_context *usb_context = NULL;
    ssize_t device_count = 0;
    bool debug_enabled = false;
    int c;

    // Collect command line attributes
    while ( (c = getopt(argc, argv, "d")) != -1) {
        switch (c) {
            case 'd':
                debug_enabled = true;
                break;
        }
    }

    // Initialize USB context
    int result = libusb_init(&usb_context);
    if(result < 0) {
        printf("Unable to initialise libusb!");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Turn debug mode on/off
    if(debug_enabled) {
        libusb_set_debug(usb_context, 3);
    }

    // Get USB device list
    device_count = libusb_get_device_list(usb_context, &usb_devices);
    if(device_count < 0) {
        puts("Unable to retrieve USB device list!");
    }

    // Iterate and print devices
    puts("VID    PID     Manufacturer Name\n------ ------ -------------------");
    for (int i = 0; i < device_count; i++) {
        print_device(usb_devices[i]);
    }

    // Attempt to send data
    send(usb_context, VID, PID);

    // Cleanup and exit
    libusb_free_device_list(usb_devices, 1);
    libusb_exit(usb_context);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

/**
 * print_device
 */
void print_device(libusb_device *device)
{
    struct libusb_device_descriptor device_descriptor;
    struct libusb_device_handle *device_handle = NULL;

    // Get USB device descriptor
    int result = libusb_get_device_descriptor(device, &device_descriptor);
    if (result < 0) {
        printf("Failed to get device descriptor!");
    }

    // Only print our devices
    if(VID == device_descriptor.idVendor && PID == device_descriptor.idProduct) {
        // Print VID & PID
        printf("0x%04x 0x%04x", device_descriptor.idVendor, device_descriptor.idProduct);
    } else {
        return;
    }

    // Attempt to open the device
    int open_result = libusb_open(device, &device_handle);
    if (open_result < 0) {
        libusb_close(device_handle);
        return;
    }

    // Print the device manufacturer string
    char manufacturer[256] = " ";
    if (device_descriptor.iManufacturer) {
        libusb_get_string_descriptor_ascii(device_handle, device_descriptor.iManufacturer,
            (unsigned char *)manufacturer, sizeof(manufacturer));
        printf(" %s", manufacturer);
    }

    puts("");

    libusb_close(device_handle);
}

/**
 * send
 */
void send(libusb_context *usb_context, uint16_t vid, uint16_t pid)
{
    libusb_device_handle *device_handle;
    device_handle = libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid(usb_context, vid, pid);

    if (device_handle == NULL) {
        puts("Unable to open device by VID & PID!");
        return;
    }
    puts("Device successfully opened");

    unsigned char *data = (unsigned char *)"test";

    if (libusb_kernel_driver_active(device_handle, CDC_DATA_INTERFACE_ID)) {
        puts("Kernel driver active");
        if (libusb_detach_kernel_driver(device_handle, CDC_DATA_INTERFACE_ID)) {
            puts("Kernel driver detached");
        }
    } else {
        puts("Kernel driver doesn't appear to be active");
    }

    int result = libusb_claim_interface(device_handle, CDC_DATA_INTERFACE_ID);
    if (result < 0) {
        puts("Unable to claim interface!");
        libusb_close(device_handle);
        return;
    }
    puts("Interface claimed");

    int written = 0;
    result = libusb_bulk_transfer(device_handle, (3 | LIBUSB_ENDPOINT_OUT), data, 4, &written, 0);
    if (result == 0 && written == 4) {
        puts("Send success");
    } else {
        puts("Send failed!");
    }

    result = libusb_release_interface(device_handle, CDC_DATA_INTERFACE_ID);
    if (result != 0) {
        puts("Unable to release interface!");
    }

    libusb_close(device_handle);
}
```

I'm getting the following error output:

```
libusb: 0.828223 error [darwin_open] USBDeviceOpen: another process has device opened for exclusive access
libusb: 0.828241 info [darwin_open] device open for access
Device successfully opened
Kernel driver doesn't appear to be active
libusb: 0.828641 error [darwin_claim_interface] USBInterfaceOpen: another process has device opened for exclusive access
Unable to claim interface!
libusb: 0.828766 info [event_thread_main] thread exiting
```

Is there a way I can release the USB device from the other process, freeing it up so I can claim it?

Is there an alternative way I can connect to /dev/tty.usbmodemfa132 to send and receive data to the CDC interface on the USB device?

An alternative to libusb perhaps?

Comment: Try `printf("Unable to claim interface: %s\n", libusb_error_name(result));` to get more info about the error.

Comment: I think I've heard something about OSX having this sort of problem with other types of composite devices as well - for example, programmers that also have a CDC serial channel.

Comment: Will it be easier to find a different way to send data? How does a terminal like zoc connect to /dev/tty.usbmodema123? I bet it doesn't use libusb.

Comment: It seems like the only solution out there for Mac is going to be involving using the termios library in C to connect directly to /dev/tty...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's right.  While libusb seems to be all-powerful in Linux, you cannot use it to connect to a USB CDC interface on Mac OS X because that interface is already claimed by the AppleUSBCDCACM driver.

What you should do is use the standard way that people connect to serial ports.  This will be easier because you don't have to worry about endpoints and bulk transfers and such.  Here is some example cross-platform C code I wrote for one of our CDC-based products that connects to a COM port to read and write some data ([source](http://www.pololu.com/docs/0J40)).  It uses the standard functions `open`, `read`, and `write`.

```
// Uses POSIX functions to send and receive data from a Maestro.
// NOTE: You must change the 'const char * device' line below.

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#define O_NOCTTY 0
#else
#include <termios.h>
#endif

// Gets the position of a Maestro channel.
// See the "Serial Servo Commands" section of the user's guide.
int maestroGetPosition(int fd, unsigned char channel)
{
  unsigned char command[] = {0x90, channel};
  if(write(fd, command, sizeof(command)) == -1)
  {
    perror("error writing");
    return -1;
  }

  unsigned char response[2];
  if(read(fd,response,2) != 2)
  {
    perror("error reading");
    return -1;
  }

  return response[0] + 256*response[1];
}

// Sets the target of a Maestro channel.
// See the "Serial Servo Commands" section of the user's guide.
// The units of 'target' are quarter-microseconds.
int maestroSetTarget(int fd, unsigned char channel, unsigned short target)
{
  unsigned char command[] = {0x84, channel, target & 0x7F, target >> 7 & 0x7F};
  if (write(fd, command, sizeof(command)) == -1)
  {
    perror("error writing");
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
}

int main()
{
  // Open the Maestro's virtual COM port.
  const char * device = "\\\\.\\USBSER000";  // Windows, "\\\\.\\COM6" also works
  //const char * device = "/dev/ttyACM0";  // Linux
  //const char * device = "/dev/cu.usbmodem00034567"; // Mac OS X
  int fd = open(device, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
  if (fd == -1)
  {
    perror(device);
    return 1;
  }

#ifndef _WIN32
  struct termios options;
  tcgetattr(fd, &options);
  options.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ECHONL | ICANON | ISIG | IEXTEN);
  options.c_oflag &= ~(ONLCR | OCRNL);
  tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options);
#endif

  int position = maestroGetPosition(fd, 0);
  printf("Current position is %d.\n", position); 

  int target = (position < 6000) ? 7000 : 5000;
  printf("Setting target to %d (%d us).\n", target, target/4);
  maestroSetTarget(fd, 0, target);

  close(fd);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's so much more than I wanted. Thanks David! I started getting into trying to see if I can use kextunload to kill the USB CDC drivers on Mac, but I think I'm overcomplicating the solution this way.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer, even though I didn't use your code. It was very helpful, and got me on the right track. I grabbed a C snippet from http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Serial_Programming/Serial_Linux#termios with tiny modifications. My version van be seen at https://gist.github.com/josefvanniekerk/7702279

Comment: since the accepted answer is more like workaround than answer to the question is it possible to do it with libusb finally?

Comment: Another option you might look into is [libserialport](http://sigrok.org/wiki/Libserialport).  I don't know if anything has changed since I wrote my answer.

Comment: unfortunately i need to test lisusb as it will be used and will work on linux

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use some USB device that is also recognised by the Apple FTDI serial driver, you can first unload the driver:

```
sudo kextunload -b com.apple.driver.AppleUSBFTDI
```

After that you can use it through `libusb` normally.

For other devices that are recognised as serial devices, you probably need to unload some other driver.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be due to a conflict between different drivers, which use the same libraries, and in my case they were related to previous Samsung device installations. i had solved this way:

```
kextstat | grep -v apple
```

To have a return like this:

```
  70    0 0x57574000 0x3000     0x2000     com.devguru.driver.SamsungComposite (1.2.4) <33 4 3>
  72    0 0x57831000 0x7000     0x6000     com.devguru.driver.SamsungACMData (1.2.4) <71 33 5 4 3>
  94    0 0x57674000 0x3000     0x2000     com.devguru.driver.SamsungACMControl (1.2.4) <33 4 3>
```

Then:

```
$ sudo kextunload -b com.devguru.driver.SamsungComposite
$ sudo kextunload -b com.devguru.driver.SamsungACMData
$ sudo kextunload -b com.devguru.driver.SamsungACMControl
```

Done. Enjoy