# Why is chrome.usb.openDevice failing?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am attempting to communicate to a USB device from a Chrome App using the [chrome.usb API](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/usb). Although I can find the device using `chrome.usb.getDevices`, I cannot connect to it using `chrome.usb.openDevice` (callback gets undefined ConnectionHandle) or `chrome.usb.findDevices` (callback gets empty list of ConnectionHandle).

Is there any way to find out why the error is happening? The [USB caveats](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_usb#caveats) section states that the device can’t be opened if an existing driver has claimed it, but I don’t think that is the case here. Is there any way to debug further? The USB guide also says that `chrome.extension.lastError` is set for transfer errors, but `chrome.extension` is undefined, so that is of little help.

I don’t think an existing driver is claiming the device. I am running Chrome on OSX, and the device is a pen that contains an Obex communications interface.

Currently, my code is basically an excerpt of the USB hello world:

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "USB Hello world",
  "version": "0.1",
  "minimum_chrome_version": "26",
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  },
  "permissions": [
    "usb",
    {"usbDevices": [
      {
        "vendorId": 7419,
        "productId": 4112
      }
    ]}
  ]
}
```

background.js:

```
var deviceId = {"vendorId": 7419, "productId": 4112},  // 0x1cfb, 0x1010 Livescribe Pulse(TM) Smartpen
chrome.usb.getDevices(deviceId, onDeviceFound);

function onDeviceFound(devices) {
  console.log("onDeviceFound", devices);
  if (0 !== devices.length) {
    var device = devices[0];
    window.device = device;
    chrome.usb.openDevice(device, onOpenDevice);
  }
}
function onOpenDevice(connectionHandle) {
  if (connectionHandle) {
    console.log("Device opened.");
  } else {
    console.log("Device failed to open.");
  }
}
```

and the console log is simply

```
onDeviceFound [{"device":6,"productId":4112,"vendorId":7419}]
Device failed to open.
```

Edit: By the way, the device does open without error on Linux.

Comment: You say "I don't think that is the case here." Why not? I typed the name of the product into a search engine and found this: https://github.com/aliendude5300/LibreScribe/issues/10 which suggests it's an HID-class device. That means you'll need to follow https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=290428 for the new API (see in-development here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/common/extensions/api/hid.idl&l=5)

Comment: @sowbug, my pen is the Pulse, which is older than the Echo mentioned in the LibreScribe issue. For me, lsusb -v (from a Linux machine) looks slightly different and has no HID information.  https://gist.github.com/yonran/9603267

Comment: I tried the chrome.hid API. Apparently it is not a HID device. (`chrome.hid.getDevices({vendorId:0x1cfb, productId:0x1010}, function(devices){console.log(devices);})` shows an array of length 0, whereas `chrome.usb.getDevices({vendorId:0x1cfb, productId:0x1010}, function(devices){console.log(devices);})` gave an array of length 1.)

Comment: This question might be relevant. You can’t use libusb to communicate to CDC interfaces on OSX. Perhaps Chrome has the same limitation as libusb. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20253350/unable-to-claim-usb-interface-with-c-libusb-on-mac-os-x

Comment: I cannot find Livescribe SDK anywhere. Does anybody have it? I can pay for it if needed. vova@77xy.net

Answer (score 0):

Try logging out `chrome.runtime.lastError()` instead.

In testing USB access on OS X, we've found that Chrome does not gain access to the USB device until the native client application (using hidapi) is running and recognizes the device.

On a Chromebook, I have found that I cannot actually access a device unless the call to `chrome.usb.findDevices()` is called from a user action.  Try adding a link to your page that calls the method and see if you get better results.