# OSX change Product ID to USB composite device

Tags: macos, usb, iokit

I've got a composite USB device i need to use under MAC OSX. Under Linux i can change the product id using the usb_modeswitch tool with the following command

`usb_modeswitch -v 0x072f -p 0x100d -V 0x072f -P 0x90cc -m 0x2 -M01b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 -r 1 -Q`

I tried to build the same tool with success using libusb under OSX 10.9.5 but when i run the application i obtain the problem reported here 
[Unable to claim USB interface with C + libusb on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20253350/unable-to-claim-usb-interface-with-c-libusb-on-mac-os-x). The proposed solution doesn't work for me because i'm not able to find a /dev/ entry for my device.

So i'm trying the code reported here [Working With USB Device Interfaces](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/devicedrivers/conceptual/USBBook/USBDeviceInterfaces/USBDevInterfaces.html) using something like

```
IOUSBDevRequest     request;

request.bmRequestType = USBmakebmRequestType(kUSBOut, kUSBVendor, kUSBDevice);
request.bRequest = 0x02;
request.wValue   = deviceAddress;
request.wIndex   = 0;
request.wLength  = length;
request.pData    = writeBuffer;

return (*dev)->DeviceRequest(dev, &request);
```

but in any case i obtain this error 0xe000404f (seems kIOUSBPipeStalled). Here is the code, i'm not sure of it, i neet to replicate the usb_modeswitch command.

[code](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3995257/usbswitch.c)

Any help would be appreciated.