# libusb_claim_interface fails on mac osx

Tags: macos, libusb, cdc, darwin

I have to use `libusb 1.0` to communicate with CDC. It will work on linux but i'm testing on Mac 10.10.3.

```
r = libusb_claim_interface(dev_handle, connection.usb_interface_index); // returns -3
```

log:

```
2015-07-02 23:43:13.901 xctest[66961:4625911] [TRACE  ] [   ]: Claiming interface ...
libusb: debug [libusb_claim_interface] interface 1
libusb: error [darwin_claim_interface] USBInterfaceOpen: another process has device opened for exclusive access
```

I've google a bit and i found USB device is opened by some system service. So it there any way to disable it or make libusb working somehow? I can't use `termios` instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are no solutions with libusb.
You should call `libusb_detach_kernel_driver` but isn't supported on Mac OS X.
Take a look here: [libusb_claim_interface fails on Mac OS X Mountain Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102168/libusb-claim-interface-fails-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/29934989)